# object reference not set to an instance of an object asp.net,

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, textbox

I have two problems:

1. how can i use textbox in other way so it wont throw any error?
2. i got an error :

   > "object reference not set to an instance of an object.

and i dont know how to fix it.
please can someone take a look?

```
protected void DataGridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.CommandName.Equals("InsertFooter"))
        {


            try
            {

                System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox txtEmp_num = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)DataGridView1.Controls[0].Controls[0].FindControl("txtEmp_num");
                System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox txtEmp_fn = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)DataGridView1.Controls[0].Controls[0].FindControl("txtEmp_fn");
                System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox txtEmp_ln = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)DataGridView1.Controls[0].Controls[0].FindControl("txtEmp_ln");
                System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox txtEmp_phone = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)DataGridView1.Controls[0].Controls[0].FindControl("txtEmp_phone");
                System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox txtEmp_email = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)DataGridView1.Controls[0].Controls[0].FindControl("txtEmp_email");

                MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connection);
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.CommandText = "insert into employees(Emp_number,First_name,Last_name,Phone_num,Email) values(@1,@2,@3,@4,@5)";



                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", txtEmp_num.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@2", txtEmp_fn.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@3", txtEmp_ln.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@4", txtEmp_phone.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@5", txtEmp_email.Text);
                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                conn.Close();
                Bind();


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Try to `debug` code and see which control is `null`..

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4660186/5836671

Answer (score 0):

`Object reference not set to an instance of an object` means that you are trying to get a property / calling a method of something which is `null`.

It means that -at least- one of your variable is null: `txtEmp_num`, `txtEmp_fn`, `txtEmp_ln`, `txtEmp_phone`, `txtEmp_email` and it is throwing you an exception when you are trying to call the `Text` property inside `AddWithValue` method

Maybe, you have some issue with the values you defined in `FindControl("txt<smth>")`

Answer (score 0):

Try it like below

```
System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox txtEmp_num=(System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBoDataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].FindControl("txtEmp_num");
System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox txtEmp_fn = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)DataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].FindControl("txtEmp_fn");
System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox txtEmp_ln = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)DataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[2].FindControl("txtEmp_ln");
System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox txtEmp_phone = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)DataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[3].FindControl("txtEmp_phone");
System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox txtEmp_email = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)DataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[4].FindControl("txtEmp_email");
```

Comment: it gives me "specified argumenr wad out of the range of valid values. parameter name:index

Comment: it returns you a reference to the TextBox you can further get the value inside the Textbox by txtEmp_num.Text property.